# How to read in a csv with datetime format DD/mm/YYYY HH:mm:ss in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read in a csv into a pandas dataframe. One of the columns is a datetime in the format DD/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss

eg 01/02/2019 12:04:40

How would I do this to ensure pandas is reading all the date times correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Have your tried 
`parse_dates = ['col1', 'col2'];
pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', header=None, names=headers, dtype=dtypes, parse_dates=parse_dates)`

Comment: To ensure you can use `.month`, `.day`, `.year` and make sure the order of parsing is correct. Because for your example, in some part of the world people would decode it as Jan 2nd, whereas in other as Feb 1st.

Comment: could you provide an example in how to ensure the order of the phrasing is correct for my example?

Comment: use dayfirst in pandas read_csv [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
you can also read first as is and change using this `df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ['01/02/2019 12:48:20', '01/02/2019 12:30:45']})
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dayfirst` argument of the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) pandas function. Supposing your csv file is called `your_csv_filename.csv` and your date column is called `name_of_date_column`:

```
import pandas as pd

date_column = ['name_of_date_column']

with open('your_csv_filename.csv') as file:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=date_column, dayfirst=True)
```